# Crash tgkill with weird weird report and no activity

Tags: java, android

I recently fixed all the nullpointerexceptions in my app, and it has around 100 daily users, 2k monthy users.

Today I got a really weird Crash report. Where it usually says

```
java.lang.Exception
com.package.app.activity
```

it just says tgkill. It is only one user who has crashes 2 times. He is on android 6.0 and has a Galaxy Note4 (trelte). Further below, where it usually says:

```
java.lang.Exception: 
  at com.package.app.MainActivity.a (Unknown Source) 
  further lines
```

it instead says:

```
backtrace:
  native: pc 000000000004276c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
  native: pc 0000000000040379  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
  native: pc 000000000001ca9b  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
  native: pc 0000000000019d19  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
  native: pc 000000000001755c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
  native: pc 0000000000008727  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+86)
  native: pc 0000000000020201  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  native: pc 000000000001d4c9  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  native: pc 000000000001f20b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  native: pc 0000000000022301  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+80)
  native: pc 0000000000010205  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+112)
  native: pc 0000000000062b23  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+70)
  native: pc 000000000003fc7b  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
  native: pc 000000000001a39b  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

What might this be?